# How to use redux options in wp-admin? wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, redux-framework

I can use redux framework options for front-end eleemnts. Now lets say if i want to change the layout(colors, background colors) of redux option panel in wp-admin using redux options, then how can i achieve this. I want to give user the option to change the layout of the option panel.

I can do this by static way but i want it to be done using redux options. is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Lead dev of Redux here. Sure, just do get_option('OPT_NAME') before you run your panel, and boom updates.

If you want to change dynamically on the fly, then there will need to be some extra work on your part. Redux can't do that for you.  :)

Comment: ok thanks i will try this tonight. one more thing i need to ask i am using type= 'image_select' i put some default images like mentioned here (Image Select Layout http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/image-select/). Now when i select image and save. i get  a value on page 1, 2 or 3 which i have put (echo `'Layout value: ' . $redux_demo['opt-layout'];`). how can i get the 1 array image url if i select 1?       '1'      => array(
            'alt'   => '1 Column', 
            'img'   => ReduxFramework::$_url.'assets/img/1col.png'
        ),

Comment: It only returns the key, never the key => value set.  ;)